# Nonlinear differential equation: reduce from second order to first order

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals, nonlinear-analysis

I've been working on this differential equation for days now but I can not find a solution. I understand that finding a solution in closed form is difficult to say (assuming there is).
What I ask is if there is a substitution (change of variables) that can "transform" this differential equation from the second order to the first order so that it is not too constrained.
Thank you for your interest and time.

$$y''(x)+ a\ x\cos y(x)=0 $$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}\ $

Comment: Why do you assume this is possible? Would you be more optimistic if you replaced the cosine by a Taylor polynomial $1-\frac12 y^2$?

Comment: If anything, I'd rather replace cosine by _sine_ ($y\mapsto y-{\pi\over2}$ or something). Not that I know what to do next, but it looks nicer this way.

Comment: I tried replacing cos (y) with its Taylor polynomial but I can not find a closed form but I've been able to calculate up to 11 series terms but I'm not enough ...

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to make it into a first degree equation. We have
$$y''(x)+ ax\cos y(x)=0$$
So we can multiply by $y'(x)$ to get 
$$y''y'+ ax\cos(y)y'=0$$

Now we can integrate to get
$$\int y''y'dx + \int ax\cos(y)y'dx=\int0dx$$
For the first integral, we can set $u=y'$, $du=y''dx$ to get
$$\int uy''dx=\int udu =u^2+C=y'(x)^2+C_1$$
For the second rule we use product rule with $f(x)=ax$ and $g'(x)=\cos(y)y'$

So we have $f'(x)=a$ and $g(x)=\sin(y)$

Now we apply integration by parts to obtain
$$\int f(x)g'(x)dx=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)dx =f(x)g(x) -\int a g'(x)dx$$
$$=f(x)g(x)-ag(x) + C_2= a(x-1)\sin(y) + C_2$$

Then we have your first order differential equation
$$y'(x)^2 +a(x-1)\sin(y(x))=C$$

Comment: I thank you for your interest, but I think there is a mistake in your resolution. Maybe I'm wrong, but I do not return the same differential equation

Comment: Do you think you point out where you think the error is? I believe I applied the integrals correctly. One problem could be that if y' is 0 at some point, it might throw things off? Also, could you provide your answer as well? Thanks!

Comment: When you  integrated  int{a*x*cos(y) y' dx} 
I do not understand how, by applying the product rule (also called integration for parts if I do not) the result is : a*x*sin(y)-int{a*cos(y)*y'*dx}

Comment: Sorry but you do not leave me your own thing, could you please (if you can) write the intermediate steps when applying the product rule?
Because, for example, I'm trying to derive the final equation out of the first order that comes out of you, but I can not go back to the starting point and verify that the result is correct

Comment: My result is:  (y' )^2+a*x*sin(y)-int{ a*sin(y) dx}=0 
but the last integral can not do it

Comment: @Christian I have written out the intermediate steps. Please look at this again to tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: @Isaac Browne : The mistake comes from your writing $g(x)=\sin(x)dy$. This is a non-sens since $g(x)$ is a finite term while $\sin(x)dy$ is an infinitesimal. If it is a typo and if you would write $g(x)=\sin(x)y$ then $g'(x)=\cos(x)y+\sin(x)y'$ which is not consistent with what is written in the integrals. That is why, definitively, your solution is false.

Comment: I meant to write sin(y). Does that not work? Its derivitive is in fact cos(y)y' by chain rule.